# How to find rules which might be conflicted in JESS?

Tags: rule-engine, jess

If i have defined set rules in jess, Is there any to find set of rules which might result into conflict based on patterns defined on LHS in rule.

(defrule rule1
  (pattern ?x)
  =>
  (printout t "rule 1 fired"))

(defrule rule2
  (pattern ?x)
  =>
  (printout t "rule 2 fired"))

Anyway to find two rules defined above will conflict in future, If not at the time of asserting a fact list of all rules which are activated?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "conflict". If there are two rules that fire under identical or almost identical circumstances, then this is either just what the programmer has wanted and it will work; it isn't a "conflict" in the common sense of the word. Although, if the result is not according to the specs, it is simply A Bug.

Finding any two non-trivial identities (your example *is* trivial) is a task that requires the answer to the question whether any set of fact object instances triggers two rules. This is equivalent to answer the question whether rule A defines a set that is a subset of what rule B defines (or vice versa).

If constraints are simple, a clever analysis of the contraining values may provide an answer - but it is, in general, not as simple as that. Constraints may make use of arbitrariliy complex functions.

Comment: Is there anything in JESS similar to drool verifier.

Comment: No, not with the Jess distribution. And, given the complexity outlined in my answer, I doubt that it can be written with reasonable effort.